# Android Tablayout select

Tags: android, select, android-tablayout

I have tablayout with two tabs in my fragment .the question is when I run this fragment it does not show my first fragment at first. But when I select second tab and come back to first one it works fine?
how can I fix this?

I have seen this : [Android TabLayout select first Tab on Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072902/android-tablayout-select-first-tab-on-startup) but it does not help at all.

```
public class FriendsFragment2 extends Fragment {

TabLayout tabs_fragment;
FriendshipFragment fragment1;
RequestFrienshipFragment fragment2;


public FriendsFragment2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container
        , @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends2, container, false);
    tabs_fragment = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs_fragment);


    setupTabLayout();

    EventTab();
    tabs_fragment.getTabAt(0).select();
    return rootView;
}


private void setupTabLayout() {

    fragment1 = new FriendshipFragment();
    fragment2 = new RequestFrienshipFragment();
    tabs_fragment.addTab(tabs_fragment.newTab().setText("two"));
    tabs_fragment.addTab(tabs_fragment.newTab().setText("one"));


}


private void EventTab() {
    tabs_fragment.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                setCurrenttabFragment(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}


private void setCurrenttabFragment(int tabPosition) {



    switch (tabPosition) {

        case 0:
        replaceFragment(fragment1);
            break;

        case 1:
            replaceFragment(fragment2);
            break;
    }
}


private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container_friends_fragment, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();

}
```

}

Comment: I am not sure why you are complicating your life. You can simply use viewpager with tabs. It has simple library that will hanlde everything for you.

Comment: i cant use ViewPager becuz its not refreshing everytime when u swip

Comment: In this case i advice you to go through fragment life cycle. You are supposed to override onResume method if you want to refresh your fragment. And also having lots of instances of fragments like in your case will slow down your app like hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first things first, you can use viewpager with tabs instead of messing up with age old codes. But still if you want to solve the issue in your known way then

1. never perform non ui related tasks in `onCreateView()`
2. Override `onActivityCreated()` and shift this part to onActivity created

``

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setupTabLayout();
    EventTab();
    tabs_fragment.getTabAt(0).select();
}
```

3. the most important part

replace `tabs_fragment.getTabAt(0).select();` with

```
tabs_fragment.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               tabs_fragment.getTabAt(0).select(); 
            }
        });
```

The issue you are facing is because your `tabs_fragment` is not yet ready and you are performing operations on it. But by following above steps it will be ensured that your tabs are ready when you perform any operation on it.

EDIT : to mark the tab as selectewd while adding itself. [According to this doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#addTab(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.Tab,%20int,%20boolean))
And then

```
private void setupTabLayout() {

    fragment1 = new FriendshipFragment();
    fragment2 = new RequestFrienshipFragment();
    tabs_fragment.addTab(tabs_fragment.newTab().setText("two"));
    tabs_fragment.addTab(tabs_fragment.newTab().setText("one"), true);


}
```

> The link you viewed has a handler with some delay.There are always chances that your view might not be ready even after that delay. So the correct method is to apply runnable to the view itself. This will ensure that runnable is called only when view is ready.

Comment: I don't Know why but it does not solve my problem.thank you for your time

Comment: I still suggest you to use viewpager with tabs. And follow proper fragment lifecycle for refresh pusposes.

Comment: i tried that too, i did use onResume and call my getData() method.and its just refreshing everytime when i swipe but it does not get data from server.

Comment: Yea, can you update the getData code too, i feel that is more important here

Comment: Please look the answer again, I updated it little bit more. Might help now

Comment: I remove my app from Emulator and install it again now its work